# C++ [[gnu::visibility("default")]] vs __declspec(dllexport) on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, attributes, visibility, declspec

I needed to make some shared libraries in C++ and I used linux as my developer operating system. I know that I need to make symbols visible if I want to load them via `dlsym`/`LoadLibrary`. So in linux all of my symbols followed this pattern:

```
extern "C" [[gnu::visibility("default")]] void f();
```

I used clang with C++11 enabled and I was able to load `f` in my host program. When I moved to windows I used GCC 4.8.2 with C++11 enabled and that pattern worked on windows machine too with `LoadLibrary`. (I needed to use C++11 for new attribute syntax). I know that on windows I need to use `__declspec(dllexport)` to export symbols from shared library. So what now? Is `__declspec(dllexport)` not required anymore?

Edit:

I found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) that those are synonyms (I think) so the question is that is there an `[[gnu::attribute]]` for `__declspec(dllimport)` to avoid using macros and `ifdef`s for specific targets?

Answer (score 5):

Symbol visibility is subtly different from `dllexport` - and the primary reason is that when you compile a `.dll` in Windows under `mingw`/`cygwin`, the default [behaviour of the linker](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/win32.html) is the option `-export-all-symbols` - i.e. it will auto-export *everything* from your `.dll` by default.

You can change this behaviour by either using a `.def` file or putting either `__declspec((dllexport))` or `__attribute((dllexport))` on *any* routine (i.e. if you specify that a single symbol is to be exported then only the symbols that are declared exported are exported). This can have a significant performance improvement at dll load time if there are a lot of symbols in your library.

If you want to use the equivalent `C++` attribute, then you use `[[gnu::dllexport]]`

So yes, use `dllexport` to keep your `.dll` from exporting the world.

In a similar manner you can use `[[gnu:dllimport]]` for importing external routines.

Careful while reading the documentation; what it actually says is that when you use the `dllexport` attribute, it also triggers the `visibility:default` behaviour unless it's overridden.

Comment: As I understand `[[gnu::dllexport]]` is for GCC only, isn't it? Is there anything like this, that works under Clang and MSVC too?

Comment: It'll work on clang as well. MSVC doesn't have the equivalent, so if you want code that's compatible across the board, you're likely going to have to resort to macros. All three compilers support the using `__declspec((dllexport|dllimport))`, so you could use that, but it's not 'clean' C++. You can only rely on the standard specified `[[ ]]` attributes if you want to guarantee platform compatible code.