# Are attributes [[gnu::dllimport]] and [[gnu::dllexport]] in clang cross-platform?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, clang, cross-platform

I'm trying to create a cross-platform shared library targeted primarily on Windows and Linux. I'm using Clang. I'm trying to be somewhat consistent with the standard specification that's why I try to get rid of some MSVC extensions where possible. One of them are `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`. What I [found out](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#dllexport) is that clang offers attributes `[[gnu::dllimport]]` and `[[gnu::dllexport]]`. The question is: are they compatible with Linux or I will still have to write macro wrappers to write cross-platform code?

[Article I've previously read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335806/c-gnuvisibilitydefault-vs-declspecdllexport-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: isnt this already answered by the Q&A you link ? I dont understand how this question is different

Comment: A quick test on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ reveals that they cause a warning on Linux. I wouldn't want to disable warnings for all unknown attributes, and the alternative is to wrap it in a macro to disable it on Linux. And at that point you might as well use `__declspec`, since it's supported by MSVC, unlike the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for that @HolyBlackCat. Good to know. I guess I just have to do it the good old way :D